# AppleScript works wonders on its own but does not work when called from the plugin

Tags: xcode, exception, plugins, applescript, applescript-objc

I know that using AppleScript cannot get access to the content of the newly created user-writing, so I use GUI Scripting. But I want Mail.app to contain its own button, which has added to the newly created files I send from my desired directory. I have a plugin for Mail.app have a script that is called by my own button. The script works wonders on its own, but it does not work when called from the plugin. What am I doing wrong?

**error**

```
{
NSAppleScriptErrorAppName = "System Events";
NSAppleScriptErrorBriefMessage = "System Events get error: Can not catch window 1 of process "Mail". Wrong index.";
NSAppleScriptErrorMessage = "System Events get error: Can not catch window 1 of process "Mail". Wrong index.";
NSAppleScriptErrorNumber = "-1719";
NSAppleScriptErrorRange = "NSRange: {0, 0}";
}
```

**and script**

```
property theMessage : ""
property allMessages : ""
property myPath : ""
property mySubfolder : "prettyAttachment"

tell application "AppleScript Utility"
    set GUI Scripting enabled to true
end tell

tell application "Mail"

try
    set allMessages to outgoing messages
    set theMessage to front outgoing message
end try

if theMessage is not equal to "" then
    tell application "Finder"
        activate
        set myPath to quoted form of POSIX path of ((path to downloads folder as string) & mySubfolder)
        set shellScriptText to "open " & myPath
        do shell script shellScriptText

        tell application "System Events"
            keystroke "a" using command down
            keystroke "c" using command down
            keystroke "h" using command down
        end tell
    end tell

    activate --mail.app

    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "Mail"
            --?set visible to true
            set allUI to every UI element of front window
        end tell
        repeat with anUI in allUI --as list
            set theRole to role of anUI
            if theRole is equal to "AXScrollArea" then
                set allSubUi to UI elements of anUI
                if (count of allSubUi) is equal to 2 then
                    --set focused of anUI to true
                    set value of attribute "AXFocused" of anUI to true
                    tell application "System Events"
                        keystroke "v" using command down
                        return true
                    end tell
                end if
            end if
        end repeat
    end tell
    end if
end tell
```

So for testing you can add some files to `prettyAttachment` folder in Download folder -> Open Mail.app and create message -> start script

**But why didn't script work in xCode bundle?
Regards and hope for help.**

**EDIT1** also see [Not able to Execute AppleScript within "Mail" application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13890369/not-able-to-execute-applescript-within-mail-application)

Answer (score 1):

Not very elegant solution, but it works. Although this is a pair of crutches in every way =)

I,m fired my script in my swizzle MailDocumentEditor class.
I removed from the script everything about focus to the body of the message and the method:

```
@interface MailDocumentEditor : DocumentEditor<...>{...}
...
- (EditingMessageWebView)webView;
...
```

and

```
@interface EditingMessageWebView : TilingWebView <...>{...}
...
- (BOOL)isActive;
- (void)paste:(id)arg1;
...
```

and all together

```
[[PrettyBundle sharedInstance] attachPrettyFiles];//fired first half of script (copy to clipboard)

MailDocumentEditor *prettyResult = (MailDocumentEditor*)self;
id prettyWebView = [pbResult webView];
[prettyWebView paste:nil];
```

that's all =)